# How to read an XML binding from Configuration into Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, binding, configuration

On a website i am maintaining dependant on customer needs, SSL is either turned on, or off.

I have the following binding set up in the applications Web.Config

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransferService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I would like to extract the binding's information and use it inside the websites application start event, but more specifically i would like to find out the security mode that is currently being used.

With this, i will be able to redirect the website to use HTTPS is the `security mode="Transport"` and not redirect if the website uses `security mode="None"`

So, how would i go about getting this binding into a controller?

I have tried the standard

`IDictionary sampleTable = ictionary)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("bindings");`

as well as something along the lines of

`string securitsetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[security]`

but as i can obviously see, it is not the correct way to go about it!

Comment: what other way you may think is the correct way?

Comment: I guess i should of described better! the reason the two ways i tried are not the correct way, is that they do not work at all!